# Do we have any design proposals?

Tags: discussion, top-7

I checked out [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) recently, and they really have a nice design. This invokes jealousy :) and a primal need to have something better ( on epic proportions ) for **Unix SE**.

So I have a nice multi-part question:

- Where and how will the site design fit into the "beta to public proccess"?
- Once we have a design, is it fixed, or can we make changes to it?
- Does anyone have any ideas to share? Seeing some mockups will really be cool :D

Comment: You really like the askubuntu-design? I think it is eyehurtingly awful!

Comment: well... I don't want anything like their design, but I like the fact that they got a design :)....

Comment: We are very proud of our design!

Answer (score 3):

Some sites have had a meta question looking for design ideas, some haven't. It looks like at some point [Jin](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jin) posts his draft design on meta ([Web Applications](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/design-ideas-for-web-applications-site-updated-with-screenshots), [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/design-ideas-for-gaming-site-updated-with-screenshots-v2), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280/design-for-webmasters-site), [Cooking](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/design-ideas-for-cooking-site)) asking for feedback, and goes through a few revisions. I imagine it will be harder to get the design changed once it's actually in place, but pretty easy when it's still being figured out

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind, though, that public launches only happen when the site has sufficient traction.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

Based on the *current* stats

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux

unix/linux has a ways to grow still. As always, [please continue to share great questions and answers!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/)

Comment: and that our traction was shot in the foot by ubuntu not being a unix or linux

Comment: @xeno that's the problem with democracy -- sometimes the people make stupid decisions :P

Comment: @Jeff though I would hardly describe this as a democracy, no offense. One democratic decision does not a democracy make.

Comment: @xeno how far down the semantics wormhole do you want to go? Is there a perfect democracy, anywhere?

Comment: That's what I like about comments, you can say that it was - in retrospect - a bad decision justified with an unfortunate non-random poll.

Comment: @xeno: so, do you know of any actual democracies? I think Debian might be one...

Comment: @SamB no, and idk if *debian* is for sure one... simply because I don't think debian *users* get to make decisions... only the *developers* do IIRC.