# Area51 visits/day count is wrong, right?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

So [Jeff](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/331/jeff-atwood) said something about Unix SE [not having enough traction yet](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/do-we-have-any-design-proposals/217#217)... which prompted me to go look at the stats displayed at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3924/unix-linux).

What caught my eyes was the visits/day stat. According to Area51 we have **432** visits per day, but on our front page it is reported that we have **1308** visits per day.

**Area51**

[image: Visits per Day]

**Unix SE front page**

[image: Visits per Day]

So which one of the two stats are wrong? OR Why are they different?

---

**update**

I checked other SE sites ( Maths and Photography ), appears that their stats are out of sync too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the homepage is misleading. There's a difference between visitors/day and views/day (if I understand it correctly):

- **visitors/day** is the number of different users that come to the site
- **views/day** is the total number of different pages the visitors view

If 10 users come to the site and each view 5 questions, we'll have 10 visitors and 50 views. Area 51 is measuring visits/day, which looks right; we generally range between 300 and 600 unique hits per day. The homepage is measuring views/day (which is why labeling it "visitors/day" seems wrong), and reports the same value that the "views_per_day" key in the [api](http://api.unix.stackexchange.com/1.0/stats) does, 1308.49. The Google Analytics info seems to put our views significantly higher (they average more like 2200), but I believe the engine does some work to filter out duplicate views that the analytics info probably doesn't include