# Area51 visits/day count doesn't match that from main site?

Tags: discussion

Area51 visits/day count is different from main site. In fact, it changed from the last time [this question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221/area51-visits-day-count-is-wrong-right) was raised, but then the number on Area51 was lower, and now it's been higher for some days now (1478/day **vs** 1540/day).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main site uses a gross average. Area 51 pulls directly from Google Analytics so it is more correct.

See [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66862/reporting-site-traffic/66896#66896) on meta.SO.